# How to implement database download at install and after in app purchase

Tags: android, sqlite, realm, google-cloud-storage, android-contentprovider

My app is an e-learning app. Content is served from a database on the user's device. Currently my database is 'Realm' and not 'SQLite'. My question is: How do I have my users download part of the database on installation and then as they progress, be able to download more of the database after making in app purchases?

I have done some reading and have come to think that the way forward, would be to use a Content Provider or Google Cloud Storage. Could you please point me in the right direction? Any tutorials would be appreciated as I am quite new to Android.

In a nutshell:

1. User installs app
2. App downloads part of the database
3. User makes an in app purchase
4. App downloads the next part of the database

I hope this isn't too much of a general question.

Answer (score 1):

My question was too much of a generalisation, but bottled down, **Firebase Database** is the way to go if your files aren't Gigabytes big. Did my research, designed my solution, works perfectly, is elegant and if anyone's interested post on this thread, I'd be glad to lay everything down, just don't know where to start laying it down from as it involves stuff that wasn't originally part of the tags I'd thought were essential.